# Display all custom post types in archives.php

Tags: custom-post-types, archives, wp-get-archives

How would I do this? 
`archive.php` only has this:

```
wp_get_archives('type=monthly');
```

And `wp_get_archives()` does not have a parameter to display all post types.

Also I think `archive-[post_type].php` is not the one I am looking for since I want all post types to be displayed in one archive page.

Thanks!

W

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you set up the right parameters for your custom post type using

```
'has_archive' => true // Will use the post type slug, ie. example
// or 
'has_archive' => 'my-example-archive' // Explicitly setting the archive slug
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type